Lambda continuously used to check the status of the database
I have an aws lambda that connects to a database and grabs some information.
I have a health endpoint created; that is just checking the database status every minute. Does it defeats the purpose of lambda being serverless.
How do you ensure that your lambda are up and working whenever they are called as per need.

Just trigger the lambda via event bridge scheduler every minute, perfectly fine.

Does calling it via EventBridge reduce the cost ? Also presently I am just calling a simple health endpoint and checking the status of my database?

Reduced the cost compared to what? It is a standard practice if you have anything that is run on a schedule.

@luk2302 if my lambda is called every minute to check the health, is it really serverless as i am incurring cost with every lambda call ? So wanted to learn what is the industry practice in such situations

Do you have anything that resembles a server? No! => serverless.

"what is the industry practice in such situations" - in multiple decades of software engineering I've never needed to check on the status of a multi-billion dollar infrastructure every minute.  You've yet to explain why you need to do this.

See monitoring and observability, if your intention is to monitor your AWS Lambda function. You haven't provided any details on the database so how best to monitor that is not something we can answer.

I am confused. You say that the Lambda function is "checking the database status every minute", but then you ask how to "ensure that your lambda are up and working". Are you worried about the Database, or are you worried about the Lambda function? What has led you to this particular worry -- have you had a failure that you wish to avoid in future?

I am concerned that the health check to database are only incrementing usage cost of the lambda. Is it really needed ? I have not seen a single instance when the database has went down so should I really use it, or there is something else I can utilize which does not incur cost to do a health check on lambda.

Triggering a lambda every minute an hitting a health endpoint will cost less than a dollar a year.
